# Deleting observations when the value of a variable is 0 for that observation using loops in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset looking like this pattern:

```
person  x1  x2  x3 
1       0   0   1 
2       0   1   0 
3       1   0   0 
4       0   1   1
```

I want to create a loop through x1 to x3 to delete observations (person) whenever x1 is 0, and then x2 is 0, then x3 is 0. Each time I will have a new dataframe.

I've tried something like this

```
df = pd.read_csv(the input file above)
for n in range(1,4):
omit = (df['x'n] == 0)
dataset[n] = df.loc[~omit]
```

But it doesn't work, and I don't even understand the error report. Can someone help me?

Comment: Currently you have an indentation error. We don't have access to the code you're running, nor the CSV (the table you've provided is not in comma separated value formatt). Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68568004/edit) to include a full error traceback and code that can copied into a clean workspace and run to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to create a dictionary of dataframes corresponding to which `x_` variable you are using to delete observations.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}, 
                   'x1': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0}, 
                   'x2': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1}, 
                   'x3': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1}})

dfs = {k:df.loc[df[f'{k}'].ne(0)] for k in ['x1','x2','x3']}
```

You can then access each dataframe with, e.g., `dfs['x1']`

```
    person  x1  x2  x3
2       3   1   0   0
```

It seems like this may be what you're trying to do as well. With some modifications, your code can accomplish the same task:

```
dataset = {}
for n in range(1,4):
    omit = (df[f'x{n}'] == 0)
    dataset[n] = df.loc[~omit]
```

Comment: Yes I tried making dataset a dictionary and it worked. Thank you.